# Redirecting browser error [header] with php session and cookie

Tags: php, session, redirect, cookies

I'm having a strange issue with my header redirection after successfull `password_verify()` Here is a part from the login.php

**login.php**

```
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM formular WHERE email='".$emailUsername."' OR username='".$emailUsername."'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

            if (password_verify($password, $row["hash"])) {
                if (isset($_POST["remember_me"])) {

                    $_SESSION["remember_me"] = $emailUsername;

                    setcookie('remember_me', md5($emailUsername . time()));
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO sessions (id) VALUES (?)");
                    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_COOKIE["remember_me"]);
                    $stmt->execute();

                    if ($stmt->affected_rows) {

                    }

                    $stmt->close();
                    $conn->close();
                }
                $_SESSION = array(
                        "login" => true,
                        "data" => array(
                                "username" => $row["username"],
                                "email" => $row["email"],
                                "time" => time() +10*5
                        )
                );
                header('Location: ../home/userarea.php');
                exit();
            }
            else {
                $errorField2 = "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">".
                    "<strong>Whoops!</strong> Wrong entries!".
                    "</div>";
            }
```

now on the top of every single page i have a file that checks if the session is set and then redirect the user to the page. and on the loginpage i have a **remember_me checkbox** that should set a **cookie** after successful entries, so that the user has not to logg in again and redirect him automatically to the userarea.php. 

***In my case any user can see userarea.php***

**bootstrap.php**

```
ob_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["login"])) {
    if ($_SESSION["data"]["time"] >= time()) {
        if(isset($_COOKIE["remember_me"])) {
            header('Location: ../home/userarea.php');
            exit();
        }
    } else {
            header('Location: ../log_reg/login.php');
            exit();
    }

} else {

    //This line here is running my browser into the redirecting error "Page could not be loaded: The called website redirects the request so that it can never be terminated."

    #header('Location: ../log_reg/login.php');
    #exit();
}
ob_end_flush();
```

this file should set a cookie if `remember_me` isset and a `session` if the user just logged in without checking `remember_me`
Cookies are allowed to set in my browser so that could't be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your issue is at the

```
isset($_SESSION["login"])
```

it is in an infinite loop, so that the redirection won't be executed :P

This is how to handle it right:

```
ob_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["login"])) {
    if ($_SESSION["data"]["time"] >= time()) {
        if(isset($_COOKIE["remember_me"])) {
            header('Location: ../home/userarea.php');
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        header('Location: ../log_reg/login.php');
        exit();
    }

} else {
    if (basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) == "login.php"){

    }
    else {
        header('Location: ../log_reg/login.php');
    }
}
ob_end_flush();
```